# How can I reduce the file size of a video encoded with wmv2 in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, video-conversion, codec, video-encoding

I have some videos of a slide presentation with audio and need to put them in a wmv container. These videos are intended to be viewed with Windows Media Player. I initially made the mistake to use the H.264 codec with libx264 encoder. It turned out that a H.264 codec inside a wmv container is not supported by Windows Media Player (even though the videos plays flawlessly in VLC on mac). I had read online that i could use the -crf flag with ffmpeg and the libx264 encoder to reduce file size - and it worked perfectly: 20-fold decrease in file-size without losing much quality (from 400MB to 30MB).

Since I need the wmv video to work on Windows Media Player and i realize H.264 is not a supported codec for wmv container, I decided to re-encode my videos with wmv2 codec. The results are horrible - 500MB+ file sizes and poorer quality. I have tried to use a lower bitrate to decrease file size, only to see that the quality turns out horrible.

Why is it that the wmv2 codec is so much worse than H.264?
How can I decrease the file sizes without losing quality with ffmpeg? Could I possibly use another codec inside the wmv container that would be recognized in Windows Media Player?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not wmv3, or even better, vc1?

Comment: @TomYan It looks like neither of them is supported by ffmpeg. Do you have another idea?

Comment: You are probably using an old version of ffmpeg. Get an updated one.

Comment: FFmpeg does not have WMV3 or VC1 encoders. I'm a Linux user, so I'm guessing Windows Media Player should support H.264 in MP4. Why not just use MP4?